# Rendimiento para los metodos de clases

Tags: javascript

A dia de hoy en javascript, realmente hay una diferencia significativa en cuanto a rendimiento si agregamos directamente metodos a una clase a que si los agregamos manualmente al prototipo de la funcion constructora?

```js
class MiClase {
  miMetodo() {}
}
 //---------------------------

function MiClase() {
  // constructor
}
MiClase.prototype.miMetodo = function() {};
```

Comment: tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, en realidad el rendimiento estara determinado por una combinacion de practicas y no necesariamente por lo wrapper que este tenga, obviamente que un mala gestion, organizacion tanto de la logica como de los wrapper tendra una incidencia en el rendimiento...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover no, la pregunta no se basa en opiniones. Es un hecho que hay una diferencia en la forma de declarar o añadir métodos a una Clase. La pregunta es: *¿Hay una diferencia significativa?* La respuesta es clara y ya la han respondido. El AP no pregunta *¿qué es mejor o cuál es la forma más óptima?* El AP claramente pregunta si la diferencia entre una forma y la otra es significativa. Para esa pregunta hay una sola respuesta, no hay opiniones o debates.

Comment: Utilizar `class` es más intuitivo; el código queda prolijo y legible; te ahorras tener que estar haciendo referencia al `prototype`. En cuanto a rendimiento, entiendo que debería ser igual aunque realmente no sé, pero si te diria que necesitas utilizar menos caracteres... :P

Answer (score 1):

Las dos declaraciones que presentas no son comparables, aunque tengan objetivos similares y aunque los usuarios la usen de igual forma la documentación nos dice lo siguiente:

### Las clases

> ***Traducción de Ingles:***
> Las clases son una plantilla para crear objetos. Encapsulan datos con
> código para trabajar con esos datos. Las clases en JS se basan en
> prototipos, pero también tienen cierta sintaxis y semántica que son
> exclusivas de las clases.
>
> Para obtener más ejemplos y explicaciones, consulte la guía [Uso de
> clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_classes).

**Repetimos y aclaramos:**

1. las clases son plantillas para objetos y métodos (código encapsulado).
2. las clases fueron creadas y basadas en prototipos, pero no son lo mismo... además de que tienen semántica y sintaxis exclusivas.
3. y una de las cosas más importante es que todas las clases tienen prototipo

### El Prototipado:

Partiendo de tu ejemplo:

```
function MiClase() {
  // constructor
}
MiClase.prototype.miMetodo = function() {};
```

en ese caso `MiClase` es un `Objeto` y no es `global` es `custom`, por lo que no es lo mismo a:

```
Object.prototype.custom = function() {}
```

En donde `Object` si es Global. Algo similar ocurre con: 
`Promise.`: que es un objeto de control de abstracción... No Global. 
`Window.`: que es un objeto apuntando a Browser Object Model... Si es Global

Referencia:
[Link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)
[Link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
[Link 3](https://jwwnz.medium.com/using-javascript-prototypes-to-add-a-custom-method-to-arrays-1cac04669ec6)

---

Una vez explicadas las diferencia de ámbito ahora un poco de arbitrariedad de conceptos... y sugar code ...

El uso de prototype está orientado a la necesidad de usar en múltiples lugares un objeto, el reciclado de código y la mejora de sintaxis orientada a proyectos grandes como frameworks... ya que esto disminuye la huella de código y el consumo de recursos en general. Lo cual es imperceptible si implementas buenas prácticas... en un proyecto no muy grande.

*En la práctica no es el cómo declares y uses las dos opciones lo que determinara lo que preguntas:*

> Una diferencia significativa en cuanto a rendimiento

El rendimiento estará siendo afectado por la calidad del código contenido en el método ... esto ocurre así porque lo que facilita `prototype` es el `indexado` de métodos dentro de la clase ... el acceder a un método de una u otra forma solo representara milésimas de segundo ... en cuanto que tu código interno del método será quien determine el tiempo que demorara la ejecución.

En cuanto a la escalabilidad, tienen el mismo índice de dificulta, peroooooo obviamente a la vista humana es más fácil trabajar con `Class`, que con `Object.Prototype`.

**Nota:** Lo que ocurre en el motor de JavaScript es otro cuento, y no es lo que estas preguntando.

---

***Class***

*Pros:*

- claridad del código.
- control sobre el ámbito de uso según implementación.

*Contra:*

- mayor consumo de recursos.
- dependencia de la calidad del código.

***Prototipado***

*Pros:*

- Recurso mínimo Manejados por el browser.
- Escalabilidad en grandes proyectos.

*Contra:*

- código difícil de leer.

**Dependencia de la declaración:**

- Ámbito de Uso Global/Local.

***Notas personales:***

El prototipado para mí es como agarrar una clase y crearle un apuntador/puntero, cada vez que lo uses para modificar algo en el objeto lo modificas en todos lados donde se encuentre la instancia de la clase... por ende la implementación de uso global y el ahorro de memoria solo será ***significativo*** cuando el proyecto escale...

***Sigo pensando que tu pregunta es muy amplia... y que el concepto en este caso de rendimiento aunado a una práctica o esquema de código, no es comparable y depende 100% de lo que estés haciendo y no de cómo lo declaras.***

Comment: Creo que lo que mencionas sobre si es global o no, esta de más. Tanto si utilizas `class` como `function` que sea "global" va a depender del contexto/entorno donde fueron declaradas.

Comment: Tiene parte (no tada la razon) y como la pregunta es: _Una diferencia significativa en cuanto a rendimiento_, este se puede percibir mas, dependiendo dende fue declarado...

Comment: ¿Como sería eso? Porque la verdad no veo como afectaría el rendimiento si ambas fueran locales o globales. Que por su naturaleza/compilador/? una sea mejor que la otra, no veo como donde fueron declaradas y en iguales condiciones cambiaria eso.

Comment: bueno no se si ustedes los programadores de javascript aplican codigo limpio y buenas practica o un minimo de estandar de arquitectura de software ...  pero lo que te digo esta basado en esos principios... dependiendo del escenario (como tu mismo lo has indicado) y tambien del codigo que se vaya a refactorizar, puede qiue cualquier de las dos opciones salgan ganando en cuestion de rendimiento ... el hecho de que sea global o local es relevante e irrelevante al mismo tiempo... todo depende de la implementacion o arquitectura...

Comment: Considero que no depende del lenguaje que se utilice para programar el desarrollar _" codigo limpio y buenas practica o un minimo de estandar de arquitectura de software"_, diría que en todo lenguaje esto depende del programador, por lo que diría que eso también esta de más  ; )

Comment: no esta demas ... por que el OP no dio el contexto completo de como implementara prototype y class ... por eso decia que esta pregunta esta basadas en opiniones ... tu tienes una forma de opinar y pensar de como deberia de funcionar y darce la respuesta y sobre todo que cosas consideras para que el rendimiento se vea afectado... y a lo mejor yo tengo otros criterios... he incluso esos criterios pueden variar a los que son los que el OP no ha dado ...

Answer (score -1):

Tal como explica en su respuesta Pablo Lozano, hay una sutil diferencia en la forma en que asignas un método a una Clase.

Lo que comenta Pablo en su respuesta es precisamente el comportamiento de la herencia por prototipos de Javascript, que no es igual a la herencia clásica de la POO que se observa en lenguajes como [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) o [java](/questions/tagged/java).

## Definición del método en la Clase

Cuando asignas un método a una Clase, como parte del constructor (en la definición de la Clase), este método o función no formará parte del Prototipo de la Clase, sino que será un propiedad directa de la misma. Y cualquier objeto creado usando este constructor heredará esta propiedad, que no será parte del [objeto `prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) presente tanto en la Clase, como en la instancia creada a partir de la misma.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class MiClaseConMetodo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Creando instancia');
  }
  miMetodo() {
    console.log(`Hola, soy un método de ${MiClaseConMetodo.name}`);
  }
}

// Objeto creado a partir del constructor de la Clase
const miObjetoConMetodo = new MiClaseConMetodo();

// Revisión del prototipo de la clase
console.log('MiClaseConMetodo.prototype:', MiClaseConMetodo.prototype);

// Revisión del prototipo del objeto
console.log('Object.getPrototypeOf(miObjetoConMetodo):', Object.getPrototypeOf(miObjetoConMetodo));

// verificamos que la Instancia tiene una propiedad llamada miMetodo
miObjetoConMetodo.miMetodo();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

## Definición del método usando `prototype` en la Clase

Cuando defines el método como parte de `prototype` de la Clase, la cosa cambia, porque ahora el objeto `prototype` contendrá el método definido allí, y todas las instancias de dicha Clase heredan este objeto llamado `prototype`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class MiClaseSinMetodo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Creando instancia');
  }
}

MiClaseSinMetodo.prototype.miMetodo = function() {
  console.log(`Hola, soy un método de ${MiClaseSinMetodo.name}`);
}

const miObjetoSinMetodo = new MiClaseSinMetodo();
// Verificamos el objeto prototype de la Clase y de la Instancia
console.log('MiClaseSinMetodo.prototype:', MiClaseSinMetodo.prototype);
console.log('Object.getPrototypeOf(miObjetoSinMetodo):', Object.getPrototypeOf(miObjetoSinMetodo));
// Verificamos que la instancia contiene un método llamado miMetodo
miObjetoSinMetodo.miMetodo();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

## Cadena de Prototipos

El comportamiento de los lenguajes que usan herencia basada en prototipos es muy simple:

1. Cuando uno invoca un método (o una propiedad) de una instancia, se busca en primer lugar en las propiedades de la instancia.
2. Si la propiedad no existe en la instancia, se busca en el objeto `protoype` de la misma.
3. Si no existe tampoco, se busca en el objeto `prototype` de la Clase de la que el objeto es instancia.

Como se puede deducir de esta cadena, si el objeto posee la propiedad buscada, el intérprete se detiene en el paso 1. Por lo cual, no necesita subir o escalar más en la cadena de prototipos.

Es por ello, que sí hay una diferencia (muy pequeña) en la forma en que se declaran los métodos o propiedades de una Clase, ya que si la defines como parte de la Clase, cuando lo uses, no habrá que recorrer la cadena de prototipos.

Para más información revisar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Comment: Como explicas [esto](https://jsfiddle.net/xqhamonc/), si según tu respuesta _"este método o función no formará parte del Prototipo de la Clase"_. Insisto, creo que se estan confundiendo con definir métodos dentro de la función, por ejemplo, [así](https://jsfiddle.net/xqhamonc/1/)

Comment: @Marcos tu primero ejemplo es incorrecto: `log` es un metodo por ende para llamarlo le tienes que poner los `()` ; de lo contrario si haces solo `.log` lo vera como que tas llamando a  una `propiedad`.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover, mi intención no era ejecutar el metodo, sino demostrar que si es parte del prototipo.

Comment: lo que pasa es que en prototype lo metodo existe tambien como definicion ...

Comment: si existen en el prototipo pero no se que relevancia tiene eso

Comment: ya te entendi... el Usuario en esta respuesta se equivoco ... todas los metodos declarado o agregados a una clase forman parte del prototipo, incluso cuando se modifican mediante la instancia tambien se cambia en todas las instancias existentes...

Comment: pero @Marcos el ejemplo que diste no era el mas acertado jajajajaja

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover, solo intente señalar que, desde mi punto de vista, esta equivocado. Si tenes un mejor ejemplo, bienvenido sea!

Comment: nah solo hay que preguntasle al Usuario que dio la respuesta, basado en que esta el argumento: _"este método o función no formará parte del Prototipo de la Clase"_