# ¿Cómo crear un objeto con funciones?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

¡Hola! tengo un pequeño dilema que creo que se puede realizar, pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo. suponiendo que tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
SaveBelvoEmpleoyeeData = async (data) => {
    return 1;
};

SaveBelvoOwnerData = async (data) => {
    return 2;
};
```

Quiero crear un objeto que, dependiendo del parámetro que yo le dé, llame a una función u otra. Creé este objeto:

```
const types = {
        EMPLOYMENT_RECORDS: this.SaveBelvoEmpleoyeeData(data),
        OWNERS: this.SaveBelvoOwnerData(data)
    }
```

El problema está, en que debugeando mi código, veo que al declarar el objeto que llamé `types`, pasa por cada método al momento de declararlo, cosa que no quiero que suceda. Yo quiero que cuando ejecute una línea como esta:

```
const result = await types[webhook_type]; //Ejemplo: si webhook_type es EMPLOYMENT_RECORDS, esperaría ver en la variable result, un 1.
```

Dependiendo el contenido de `webhook_type`, llame a un método o al otro. Actualmente, esa línea no hace nada. Sé que tengo que cambiar la declaración del objeto llamado `types`, pero no sé cómo deba de ir, y tampoco encontré algo útil por internet, posiblemente porque no pude explicarme bien, jajaja. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo puedo realizar esto?
Toda ayuda será bien recibida :)

Comment: hace poco hablamos sobre un tema parecido

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Rendimiento para los metodos de clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/612194/rendimiento-para-los-metodos-de-clases)

Comment: hay dos formas, mediante clases y prototipado, creo que hay mas... pero estas son las mas usadas

Comment: creo que sí, me da una idea que voy a probar ahora mismo, y si me da resultados los compartiré por aquí :D

Comment: bueno, como haya solo mencionan 2, aqui he mencionado otras formas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te puendo mencionar 4 formas de crear Objetos en javascript en el cual esten los metodos/funciones:

***Forma 1:*** Utilizando la sintaxis de objeto literal

```
const miObjeto1 = {
  propiedad1: 'valor1',
  propiedad2: 'valor2',
  miFuncion1: function() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion1!');
  },
  miFuncion2() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion2!');
  }
};
```

---

***Forma 2:*** Utilizando la función constructora

```
function MiObjeto2() {
  this.propiedad1 = 'valor1';
  this.propiedad2 = 'valor2';
  this.miFuncion1 = function() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion1!');
  };
  this.miFuncion2 = function() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion2!');
  };
}

const instanciaObjeto2 = new MiObjeto2();
```

---

***Forma 3:*** Utilizando la clase (introducida en ECMAScript 6)

```
class MiObjeto3 {
  constructor() {
    this.propiedad1 = 'valor1';
    this.propiedad2 = 'valor2';
  }

  miFuncion1() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion1!');
  }

  miFuncion2() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion2!');
  }
}

const instanciaObjeto3 = new MiObjeto3();
```

***Puedes llamar a las funciones de la siguiente manera:***

```
miObjeto1.miFuncion1();
instanciaObjeto2.miFuncion2();
instanciaObjeto3.miFuncion1();
```

---

***Forma 4:*** y Adicional la Implementacion de prototype:

```
// Forma 3: Utilizando la clase (introducida en ECMAScript 6)
class MiObjeto3 {
  constructor() {
    this.propiedad1 = 'valor1';
    this.propiedad2 = 'valor2';
  }

  miFuncion1() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion1!');
  }

  miFuncion2() {
    console.log('¡Hola desde miFuncion2!');
  }
}
```

***Puedes llamar a las funciones de la siguiente manera:***

```
const instanciaObjeto3 = new MiObjeto3();
instanciaObjeto3.miFuncion1();
```

Answer (score 2):

después de buscar un rato, e inspirado por la respuesta de [Francisco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/612276/45793), llegué a mi solución. Primero, se modifica el objeto `types` para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
const types = {
        EMPLOYMENT_RECORDS: (data) => this.SaveBelvoEmpleoyeeData(data),
        OWNERS: (data) => this.SaveBelvoOwnerData(data),
    };
```

Lo que cambió, principalmente, es que, al utilizar funciones flecha, le indico al código que es una función, y que no debe llamar al método que estaba en un principio al momento de crear el objeto, que era lo que me estaba sucediendo en un principio. Los métodos `SaveBelvoEmpleoyeeData` y `SaveBelvoOwnerData` no sufrieron ninguna modificación.

También, la línea con la que llamo a los métodos la modifiqué, para pasarle la variable que requiere cada método para ser ejecutada:

```
const result = await types[webhook_type](data);
```

Con estos cambios, el código presentado en mi pregunta funcionó como lo esperaba en un principio. Muchas gracias por su apoyo :)

Comment: muy bien, que bueno el poder haberte ayudado.